# Design approach to decouple DB write to reduce application latency

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-sqs, system-design

I want to use DynamoDB to save application operation data at the end of a session for auditing purposes without affecting the actual application latency. Should I decouple the DB write activity with a SQS? So, the Db write delay will have no effect on the actual application? or what would be the best design technique for dealing with these scenarios?

Comment: This is an opinion question, open ended that probably belongs better on https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ than here - mostly because your question revolves a lot around your particular use case and your requirements. If response time is a requirement, then yes this is possible. But there is a delay - if that matters (an audit trail may not).

Comment: You should benchmark it, but my gut feeling is that writing to a DynamoDB table which has a certain minimum amount of throughput (as DynamoDB tables will get faster the more throughput they have) will be faster than submitting the data to SQS.